# merge a data frame out put of a column

Tags: r, dataframe, calculated-columns, quanteda

I have a `data.frame` with two variables: `ID` and `Text`
I am using the following text analysis command that gives a `data.frame` output of 48 columns.

```
analysis <- textstat_readability(mydata$text,  measure = c("all"), remove_hyphens = TRUE)
```

How can I add those 48 columns of results as separate columns in `mydata`?

Currently I am using the following:

```
analysis <- cbind(mydata$ID[1:100000], textstat_readability(mydata$text[1:100000],  measure = c("all"), remove_hyphens = TRUE))
```

But it takes forever to finish.

Answer (score 1):

You have 100.000 records with text. Depending on your system and how big each text record is, that might take a while. You could try speeding up the process by using more cores. Most of quanteda's processes run in parallel so it is worth a shot.

Try to do the following to see if that speeds it up:

```
library(quanteda)
# use all available cores - 1
quanteda_options(threads = parallel::detectCores() - 1)

analyses <- textstat_readability(mydata$text[1:100000],  measure = c("all"), remove_hyphens = TRUE)

analyses <- cbind(mydata$text[1:100000], analyses)
```

Testing this with an a data.frame filled with 2000 times the data_char_sampletext didn't show much difference if you want to do it in one `cbind` action. But that depends on how big your mydata data.frame already is. It might be better to do it in 2 steps.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why your approach takes forever to finish to be honest, but the correct way to do it would be the following, I think:

```
# (0.) Load the package and make a random sample dataset (usually this should be
# provided in the question, just saying):

library(quanteda)
mydata <- data.frame(ID = 1:100,
                     text = stringi::stri_rand_strings(
                       n = 100, 
                       length = runif(100, min=1, max=100), 
                       pattern = "[A-Za-z0-9]"),
                     stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# 1. Make a quanteda corpus, where the ID is stored alongside the text column:

mydata_corpus <- corpus(mydata, docid_field = "ID", text_field = "text")

# 2. Then run the readability command:

`analysis <- textstat_readability(mydata_corpus,  measure = c("all"), remove_hyphens = TRUE)`

# 3. Now you can either keep this, or merge it with your original set based on
# IDs:

mydata_analysis <- merge(mydata, analysis, by.x = "ID", by.y = "document")
```

This should work without you having to use `cbind()` at all.